# Automate python script to run and generate csv file every 2 hours

Tags: python, csv, automation

So, I have a python code like this,

```
from arcgis.features import SpatialDataFrame
fl = known_item.tables[0]
# Use the `from_layer` method of the Spatial DataFrame to create a new Spatial DataFrame
sdf = SpatialDataFrame.from_layer(fl)

df = sdf.copy()
df = df[df["site_status"]!="Closed"]
print(len(df))
df.head()
## save the file to local directory
df.to_csv(path+'Status.csv')
```

As you can see, the code outputs a csv file. I saved the csv file to my local directory. All I want to do is just to run the code automatically every 2 hours and generate a new csv file. So, every 2 hours the new csv file will overwrite the old one.

I dont have much knowledge about automation so any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are probably looking for Cron / cronjob https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I dont have access to cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a sleep for 2 hours and put the whole code in a for loop

```
import time
from arcgis.features import SpatialDataFrame
for i in range(100):
  fl = known_item.tables[0]
  # Use the `from_layer` method of the Spatial DataFrame to create a new Spatial DataFrame
  sdf = SpatialDataFrame.from_layer(fl)

  df = sdf.copy()
  df = df[df["site_status"]!="Closed"]
  print(len(df))
  df.head()
  ## save the file to local directory
  df.to_csv(path+'Status.csv')
  time.sleep(60*60*2)#60 seconds*60 minutes*2 = 2 hours
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Your code worked and updating csv file every 2 hours. Could you tell me why you used for i in range(100)? thanks.

Comment: Look that is a for loop, it will run (100) times, but you can increase the number or put the for loop under while True: so that it runs infinitely

Answer (score 0):

well, there's a simple way to achieve that! you could wrap your code around a while loop and add a time.sleep() function at the end of the loop body.

```
from arcgis.features import SpatialDataFrame
import time

while True:
    fl = known_item.tables[0]

    # Use the `from_layer` method of the Spatial DataFrame to create a new Spatial DataFrame
    sdf = SpatialDataFrame.from_layer(fl)

    df = sdf.copy()
    df = df[df["site_status"]!="Closed"]
    print(len(df))
    df.head()

    ## save the file to local directory
    df.to_csv(path+'Status.csv')
    
    # wait for 2 hours
    time.sleep(7200)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested it with 5 minutes interval. It runs the code first time and put the csv file in the directory but doesn't do anything after 5 minutes pass. Do I have to  schedule it to run for every 2 hours?

Comment: Hi I saw that you have accepted the other answer. Anyway, my codes should loop infinitely until you end the program. I'm not sure why it didn't do anything after 5 minutes. Perhaps you have set the 5-min interval wrong?

Comment: My fault. Your answer is also correct. My csv file was open thats why it couldn't update the new file. I just figured it out. Thanks a lot.